# Can I remotely add/delete my iPad application with an Apple Enterprise?

Tags: iphone, security, deployment, operating-system, enterprise

I have an iPad application that will be deployed in an enterprise enviroment to a number of devices within my company.

The thing is we **don't** want to have to put up a MDM server.

so the question is, can we remotely install or uninstall the application just with the tools from an Apple Enterprise account?

Thanks in advance for all insight

Comment: I will suggest you to look at TestFlight. just google it.

Comment: I generally send them the device build or simulator build. By giving them the simulator build avoid to add the UDID of each device to provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I need the tools to install/uninstall applications in a Enterprise enviroment, not to do widespread beta testing.

Comment: I just wrote a shell script which delete the build folder from app bundle path and copy the new one to same path.

Comment: Some MDMs like Mobile iron have silent app installation feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than an MDM server, you can install an enterprise app by dragging it into iTunes. Alternatively, you can use a tool Apple provides for both Mac OS X and Windows called Apple Configuration Utility, available at: http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/

However, setting up an MDM server is very practical with even a small number of users to support, basically because both of the others require physical access to a desktop computer.

Comment: In addition to MDM server,iTunes and Apple configuration utility you could use iPCU(iPhone Configuration Utility) to install apps on iOs devices which is available for both mac as well as windows.